# How can I generate a PDF file from Amazon Textract output?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf, fpdf

I am using Amazon Textract to extract data from a scanned document. Now I want to convert the output to a PDF file. Below is a sample output of Textract:

```
[1] => Array
                    (
                        [BlockType] => LINE
                        [Confidence] => 99.4744720459
                        [Text] => Hello
                        [Geometry] => Array
                            (
                                [BoundingBox] => Array
                                    (
                                        [Width] => 0.243866533041
                                        [Height] => 0.0134594505653
                                        [Left] => 0.176409825683
                                        [Top] => 0.0463116429746
                                    )

                                [Polygon] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [X] => 0.176409825683
                                                [Y] => 0.0463116429746
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [X] => 0.420276373625
                                                [Y] => 0.0463116429746
                                            )

                                        [2] => Array
                                            (
                                                [X] => 0.420276373625
                                                [Y] => 0.0597710944712
                                            )

                                        [3] => Array
                                            (
                                                [X] => 0.176409825683
                                                [Y] => 0.0597710944712
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [Id] => 75e8917d-701e-4e26-bade-f00bde9d87db
                        [Relationships] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [Type] => CHILD
                                        [Ids] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => 46f44500-4960-4405-99f3-fa43101bc2ca
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )
```

As you can see, the output contains text, height, width and its XY coordinates. How can I place the text with same co-ordinates into a PDF file?

Comment: Do you want to superimpose the text onto an existing PDF or do you want to create a PDF from scratch using this information?  Another way to ask it is are you filling out a form with this data, or creating an entirely new documents.

Comment: @user1153660 I am trying to create a PDF from scratch with this data.

Comment: @Sreeraj did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can convert the above to JSON, you can use [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) or [PDFkit](http://pdfkit.org/) to create the PDF.  The functionality maps pretty well based upon the limited data you posted, but I have not seen the full structure of Textract as it is still in Beta and I didn't get an invite to the program.  Both these projects can use Node to create a server-side solution, but they also work in the Browser.

At the time of this writing, Google Cloud has an OCR component in their [Vision - Document Text Detection](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr) feature.  Unlike Textract, it approaches the task as just reporting what visual elements the document has and creating a comprehensive (and large) data structure that describes what it "sees."  Textract, according to Amazon, uses machine learning to organize the data in a more human understandable form that seeks to differentiate the form from the data that constitutes the filled-out part of the form. If you are trying to create a relatively complete PDF, the Google product is well suited.  Textract might be too, but I don't know yet.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-textract-searchable-pdf) repository contains code examples (in Java) showing how you can generate a searchable PDF using AWS Textract. If you are not using Java, you may also deploy it as an AWS Lambda function and then invoke it via the AWS SDK or as a REST API call using AWS API Gateway.

There is a corresponding blog post also available [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/generating-searchable-pdfs-from-scanned-documents-automatically-with-amazon-textract/).